# Firebase queries blog post doesn't have any content

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to read firebase's blog post about advanced queries (https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/01/2014-11-04-firebase-realtime-queries.html) but when I hit the page, the content of the post is empty.

What's going on with this post? Where else can I find guidance on firebase advanced queries?

Thanks

Comment: It was removed. https://www.google.co.in/#q=firebase+realtime+database+query

Comment: But there are references to this post on their other posts. I guess they've forgotten  to remove these references